# Fitting a gamma distribution to truncated data

Tags: maximum-likelihood, optimization, gamma-distribution, point-estimation, truncation

I am faced with the following truncation problem:

$$
X_i \sim \Gamma(\alpha, \beta) \\
\delta_i = \chi(X_i \le \tau_i)
$$

I can observe only $(X_i, \tau_i)$ where $\delta_i = 1$ and I have no a-priori information about the total number of observations.

Trying to fit $X_i$ leads to a log-likelihood with an additional term

$$\log\mathcal L(\alpha, \beta ; x_i) = \sum_{i=1}^{N}\log f_X(x_i;\alpha, \beta) - \sum_{i=1}^N \log 1 - P_X(\tau_i; \alpha, \beta)$$

Where $f_X$ and $P_X$ are PDF resp. CDF of the gamma distribution. Note that the first term is "just" the regular log-likelihood for $Y\sim\Gamma(\alpha,\beta)$ and the second term relates to the truncated samples.

Now, for the exponential case ($\alpha\equiv 1$) I managed to efficiently estimate this likelihood in R using

```
set.seed(42)
r <- 2
Ntrue <- 1000
xtrue <- rexp(Ntrue, r)
ytrue <- runif(Ntrue)
tau  <- 2
obs <- xtrue + ytrue < tau
x <- xtrue[obs]
t <- tau - ytrue[obs]
rhat <- optimize(
    function(r) {log(r) - r * mean(x) - mean(log(1 - exp(-r * t)))},
    c(1e-4, 1/mean(x)),
    maximum = TRUE
)$maximum
# = 1.927
```

A straight-forward generalization of this approach using general gamma distributions bears no success, however:

```
set.seed(42)
r <- 2
Ntrue <- 1000
xtrue <- rexp(Ntrue, r)
ytrue <- runif(Ntrue)
tau <- 2
obs <- xtrue + ytrue < tau
x <- xtrue[obs]
t <- tau - ytrue[obs]
llik <- function(shape, rate) {
    mean(dgamma(x, shape = shape, rate = rate, log = TRUE)) -
        mean(pgamma(t, shape = shape, rate = rate, lower.tail = FALSE, log.p = TRUE))
}
rhat <- optim(c(shape = 1, rate = 1), 
              fn = function(x){-llik(shape = x["shape"], rate = x["rate"])})$par
# Way off (2.03e50, 2.39e52) and warnings related to NaNs in {d,p}gamma.
```

Do you have any guidance on how to optimize the penalized likelihood?

Comment: Is there any reason why you are not using the survreg function from the survival package to do this?

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but does survreg deal with unknown sample sizes?
I don't have censoring in the individual observations, only non-random completely missing observations.

Comment: Do you know the $\tau_i$?  Are they (possibly) different for each $i$?

Comment: @EmmaJean: Looks like plain unpenalized ML to me:

> 1/unique(predict(survival::survreg(survival::Surv(x)~1, dist = "exponential")))
[1] 2.355137
> 1/mean(x)
[1] 2.355137

Comment: @jbowman Yes, I do (I'll try to clarify - note the logL contains $\tau_i$-terms) And yes, they are.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The contribution to your log-likelihood function due to the truncation should be $\log P_X(\tau_i;\alpha,\beta)$ not $\log 1 - P_X(\tau_i;\alpha,\beta)$. Thus, I think you just need to change `lower.tail = FALSE` to `lower.tail = TRUE` in your llik function.

Also, you are conflating censoring with truncation. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncation_(statistics)),

> Truncation is similar to but distinct from the concept of statistical censoring. A truncated sample can be thought of as being equivalent to an underlying sample with all values outside the bounds entirely omitted, with not even a count of those omitted being kept. With statistical censoring, a note would be recorded documenting which bound (upper or lower) had been exceeded and the value of that bound. With truncated sampling, no note is recorded.

Finally, I wouldn't call this a penalized likelihood but just a likelihood.